# How to build multiple maven projects in one step without a common parent?

Tags: maven-2

I have read that to build multiple Maven projects in one step (with automatic building of dependencies) the Maven reactor plugin can be used. However, all the examples I have seen show that in order to use this plugin, the interdependent packages are modules of a common parent project.

Is it possible to use maven to build multiple projects in one step which are not modules of a common parent project?

For example - two projects from different repositories, one project depends on another, and I want to make local changes to both projects and build everything in one step. Can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to use maven to build multiple projects in one step which are not modules of a common parent project?

No, you need a **aggregating** project i.e. a project listing them as modules (and the sub-modules don't have to inherit from the aggregating project).

- Related Stack Overflow question: [What is the "reactor" in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050241/what-is-the-maven-reactor)
- Refer to "3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance" of [Maven: The Complete Reference | POM Best Practices](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html)

Comment: I believe this answer is not that accurate.
In Maven, Aggregating (aka Multi-Module project) is not necessary to be Parent project

Comment: @Adrian Hmm... Maybe I was not clear enough but that's not what I meant. I only meant that for a reactor build, you need an aggregating project (listing the modules).

Comment: That sonatype.com link is broken.