# Maven release:prepare plugin fails a multi-module build which has got inter-module dependency

Tags: maven

I have got a multi-module Java project which has got inter-module dependency. When I try to build this project using `mvn -e --batch-mode release:prepare -DdryRun -DreleaseVersion=1.2.999` it fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
....
```

This seems to me like a known limitation of release:prepare plugin. What are the possible workarounds?

Apologies if this problem has been posted before...your suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. This question doesn't have a final convincing answer [How to release Maven multi-module project with inter-project dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166752/how-to-release-maven-multi-module-project-with-inter-project-dependencies))

Regards,
Benil

Comment: That looks more like a problem with dependencies which are SNAPSHOT's instead.

Comment: Snapshot dependencies are needed if one wants to perform a release with maven release plugin. If I remove snapshot dependency, then I may have to do separate release of each module which have got inter-dependencies. I am not sure if that is the best solution.

Comment: In this case the dependencies for other libs etc. are the case not the inter dependencies between the modules. Is this project somewhere online (may be on github?)

Comment: The error I receive is for the project modules (and not third party modules). Unfortunately this is an enterprise project and therefore not available for online. Note that I can still compile and package the project through 'mvn clean deploy' but I am interested in getting it run through maven release plugin.

Comment: Create a content reduced equivalent of that and see if you can reproduce this behaviour and show it here.