# Maven Application got 5 Modules and 6 POM.xml files

Tags: maven-2

I am working on existing Maven Project 
Which has got 5 modules like

```
 <modules>
    <module>sideware</module>
    <module>xmlmodule</module>
    <module>business</module>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>helper</module>
</modules>
```

Each Module has got a one POM.xml file as well as

and one main  Pom.xml

I am using Eclipse to run the POM.xml files as Maven install

Please tell me do i need to run the Each POM.xml indivudally ??

Or can i run the Parent POM.xml file once ??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is sufficient to run the parent POM. See the question [What is the "reactor" in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050241/what-is-the-maven-reactor) about the plugin that implements that for Maven. So you have the following options (at least):

- Build the parent POM, which will build all modules as well.
- Build a module individually, and it will build its dependencies automatically.

Here is a small experiment I have done on my own:

1. Build automatically == false. 
   [image]
2. Build a multi-module Maven project, and add there 2 modules.[image]
3. Insert some code into the modules. [image]
4. Run `mvn install` inside eclipse [image]

As a result, I get the following output in the console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   MultiModuleExample
[INFO]   Unnamed - com.tsi.mli:sideware:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   Unnamed - com.tsi.mli:business:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MultiModuleExample
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing C:\projekte\setools-work\build\example-build-projekte\indigo-full\ws\multi-module-example\pom.xml to C:\Users\mliebelt\.m2\repository\com\tsi\mli\multi-module-example\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\multi-module-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.tsi.mli:sideware:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
...
```

The directory structure I have got is:

```
multi-module-example/
  business/
    src/
    target/
    .classpath
    .project
    pom.xml
  sideware/
    ...
  src/
  .project
  pom.xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i ran just the Parent POM.xml , it gave me this error ,  The project com.tata:tata-mw:1.0 (D:\tata\middleware\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.tata:bayer:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 12 -> [Help 2]

Comment: I have added my structure of the directory. There seems to be a difference, your parent pom is not automatically found. But that is another story ...