# maven fails to resolve dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I have multi module maven project.When I try to build site, e.g. execute `maven site` on parent project it fails to resolve dependency to one of modules.
But if I just compile (`mvn clean compile` on parent project) it or run tests (`mvn clean test` on parent project) there are no dependency problems.

What could cause such behaviour?

**UPD**

Maven version

```
Apache Maven 3.0.2 (r1056850; 2011-01-09 02:58:10+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_26, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

maven-site-plugin version

```
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:2.0.1
```

Error message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproj-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project mycompany.myproj:myproj-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact mycompany.myproj:myproj-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project myproj-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project mycompany.myproj:myproj-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact mycompany.myproj:myproj-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project mycompany.myproj:myproj-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact mycompany.myproj:myproj-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:165)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact mycompany.myproj:myproj-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:526)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifacts(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:304)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:150)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact mycompany.myproj:myproj-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:517)
    ... 26 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :myproj-client
```

Comment: what version of maven and what version of site plugin?

Comment: @jtahlborn, updated question with maven version. There are no site plugins defined explicitly in pom files.

Comment: if you run mvn with the -X argument, it will spit out reams of information.  that should enable you to determine the version of the various libs you are using.

Comment: @jtahlborn, updated question with maven site plugin version

Comment: Can you include the exact error message?

Comment: k, looks like you are running an outdated version.  the version 2 site plugin is at version 2.3, and it looks like there is a version 3 site plugin as well.  the older version of the plugin may not be compatible with maven 3.

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem. I didn't dig into Maven's source code too much. But here is my observation.

Supposed that you never `mvn install` *myproj-common* in your local repository, neither deployed it onto any remote repositories. When you run `mvn clean site` on the parent project, things happen like this:

1. maven determines the order of *myproj-common* is before
   *myproj-client* according to their dependency relationship
2. `mvn clean site` is run on *myproj-common*. All previous result in *myproj-common/target* are deleted and *myproj-common/target/site* is
   generated. (Note that after this step, neither compiled classes nor packaged jar exists in  *myproj-common/target*)
3. `mvn clean site` is run on *myproj-client*. Maven first checks the
   dependency of this project, and tries to find *myproj-common*'s
   artifact (classes or jar) in these places: (a) *myproj-common/target* (b) local repository (3) remote repositories.
4. `mvn site` fails on *myproj-client*, since it cannot find the artifact of *myproj-common*

This explains why `mvn clean compile site` and `mvn clean package site` works. They both would have prepared *myproj-common* artifacts in its target directory before `mvn site` runs on *myproj-client*.

And `mvn install` followed by `mvn site` works also.

A special exception is that if you put something like emma-maven-plugin in reporting, it will automatically compile and instrument classes. In this case, `mvn clean site` always works.

I am not sure why Maven tries to find *myproj-common*'s jar in step 3, it seems to have nothing to do with `mvn site`. The exception happens quite early in maven core, before getting into maven-site-plugin. It looks not like a problem of maven-site-plugin but a common behavior of all maven lifecycles (except *clean* I believe).

Answer (score 5):

i was facing the same but for struts and paypal_base dependecies, i fixed by doing following.

1. i checked, and found that jar files didn't exists in appropriate folder in maven repository(.m2/reposotory....).
2. I have installed that jar files via following mvn command

   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Dependencies\paypal_base.jar \
     -DgroupId=paypal -DartifactId=paypal_base -Dversion=0.1 \
     -Dpackaging=jar

and

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Dependencies\struts.jar \
  -DgroupId=struts -DartifactId=struts -Dversion=0.1 \
  -Dpackaging=jar
```

(-DFile is the location of jar file in you system)

3. Rebuild the project by Maven.
4. My Project was successful build.

you must check the jar, and use above instruction is jar not exist.
may be this will helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This might be an issue with the site plugin not having access to the reactor, and thus not seeing that the project artifact is available in your project sources. (This is merely a hypothesis, perhaps supported by [MSITE-302](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSITE-302).)

Try running first `mvn install`, which installs your artifacts in the local repository, and then running `mvn site`.

For more information on the reactor, try:

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html
- [What is the "reactor" in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050241/what-is-the-maven-reactor)

Comment: Is it necessary to run install each sub project?

Comment: No, running it on your main module will include the sub-modules.

Answer (score 1):

Heh, for some reason, after I made some changes to module and parent pom files, problem vanished. I don't know exactly what was done, but currently `mvn site` on parent project is working normally. Unfortunately I have no time to investigate what is the roots of the problem. But it seems that changing site version to 3.0 put me on the right way. Also I could execute site (before it was fixed) in the following way `mvn compile site`, in this case it could find dependency.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like maven is looking for myproj-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in the repository.

The reason for failure could be:
maven is not able to access the snapshot artifacts in the repository.

To enable snapshot artifacts:

please check you pom.xml for *snapshots* tag under the repository section.

```
<repository>
   <name>xyz</name>
   <id>repoid</id>
   <url>http://x.y.z</url>
   <releases>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Comment: the OP indicated that normal compilation works fine, so i doubt that's the issue.